# Get TotalLoss of a Checkpoint file

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have 100s of checkpoint files and I need to pick one that will have the TotalLoss best suited to my needs.

How can I get that information through the python classes?

Edit: TF 1.x

Answer (score 0):

TotalLoss is a value calculated on your data. The tensorflow model and it's weights do not store any dataset information. The rule of thumb would be: if you have to feed data to calculate a value, such as loss, gradient, accuracy etc. this can not be derived from the model alone and would not be visible from checkpoint, unless designed otherwise.

To calculate total loss of all the checkpoints you have to load each of them and run loss evaluation on the dataset you have.

To avoid reruns you can store the loss value in a variable and save it along with the model, so you can read it later.

Comment: Would it be possible to inherit the TF Saver and implement it there?